# pdal tile to generate TIFFs without seams

Tags: pdal

I'm using a pdal tile command like the one below.  This works, and creates tiles of Z dimension in a TIFF.  However, the edges of each tile create a seam (seen below).

I tried setting the buffer to 1 but that had no effect.  It seems logical that the cause is because the points are clipped while streamed before determining the mean value vs. instead using a buffer into the neighboring tiles to get that mean before the clipping, just guessing.

The goal is to take about 8500 LAS files and tile them into TIFFs of various kinds.

4 las files

```
docker run --rm -v ~/:/data pdal/pdal pdal tile "/data/las-demo/*.las" "/data/las-demo/outfile_#.tif" --writers.gdal.resolution=1 --buffer=1
```

[image]

Comment: I would suspect this is caused by your style stretching each tile to its local min/max and not a fixed one

Comment: Spot on @IanTurton.  The contrast enhancement for each tile was set to stretch, changing it to "No Enhancement" fixed it, no seams.

Answer (score 1):

I made sure the contrast enhancement for each tile was set to "No Enhancement" and that resolved the issue.

[image]